# how to add rspec for paperclip gem validation for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a `Post` model like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image,
                    styles: { large: "500X500",
                              medium: "300x300>",
                              thumb: "100x100#" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Comment: Doesn't paperclip already test that?

Comment: I dont know about that, but i need to define the test cases using rspec

Comment: @JagdeepSingh what i need to give in factories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want to write a test for, but you can use [Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers) to write simple ones:

```
describe Post do
  # For: `has_attached_file :image`
  it { should have_attached_file(:image) }

  # For: `validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/`
  it { should validate_attachment_content_type(:image).
              allowing('image/png', 'image/gif').
              rejecting('text/plain', 'nonimage/something') }
end
```

Comment: 1) Post Post should have attached file :image
     Failure/Error: it { should have_attached_file(:image) }
       expected #<Post:0x00007fe65fdaaf78> to respond to `has_attached_file?`
     # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

 this is the error i am getting how tot resolve

Comment: Thank you i got the solution